# Can I schedule controller methods in rails using rufus-scheduler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rufus-scheduler

Could I schedule the index method from the controller posted below? If so, how would I go about doing that?

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
   if Number.find(1)
    @number = Number.first
    @number.value += 1
    @number.save
   else 
    @number = Number.new    
    @number.value = 0
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: You should be able to call the same code that is called inside a controller right at the scheduler. If you can't, decouple the code from the controller to a separate class and you will be able to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the etiquette is here? Do you want to post this as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you seem to have a Number model. The first step would be to move your logic from the controller to the model:

```
class Number

  def self.increment

    n = nil

    if Number.find(1)
      n = Number.first
      n.value += 1
      n.save
    else
      n = Number.new
      n.value = 0
    end

    n
  end
end
```

Your controller then becomes

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index

    @number = Number.increment
  end
end
```

Then this "increment" class method can be called from the scheduler too. Like in:

```
# file:
# config/initializers/scheduler.rb

require 'rufus-scheduler'

# Let's use the rufus-scheduler singleton
#
s = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton


# Stupid recurrent task...
#
s.every '10m' do

  Number.increment
end
```

Now if this answer too goes way above your head, consider registering for a Rails developer course. Please realize that people are here to help you, not to do your job for free.

Comment: Thanks for your help, sorry I'm a newbie. I've done the Rail Tutorial by Michael Hartl and a number of online tutorials but I struggle a lot with implementing gems and understanding documentation. Unfortunately, there isn't a rails class or anything where I live otherwise I'd totally go. This isn't a job for me, just trying to learn and figure things out. Sorry if I stepped on your toes.

Comment: sorry, why could not we call a method defined in a controller directly from scheduler?

Comment: You can, but it's poor structuring. Methods in a controller are meant to fulfill web requests, not scheduler imperatives. Better have the "method" in a helper or library class/module and call it from the controller and/or from the scheduled job.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to initialize a rufus-scheduler instance. This is usually done in a Rails initializer:

```
# config/initializers/scheduler.rb

require 'rufus-scheduler'

# Let's use the rufus-scheduler singleton
#
s = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton

# Stupid recurrent task...
#
s.every '1m' do

  Rails.logger.info "hello, it's #{Time.now}"
end
```

Your controller can then use the rufus-scheduler instance, as in:

```
class ScheController < ApplicationController

  def index

    job_id =
      Rufus::Scheduler.singleton.in '5s' do
        Rails.logger.info "time flies, it's now #{Time.now}"
      end

    render :text => "scheduled job #{job_id}"
  end
end
```

This works well with Webrick and Thin, but requires some tuning with Passenger or Unicorn (preventing multiple schedulers and/or preventing the initial rufus-scheduler thread from vanishing).

Comment: Could you revise your answer to fit the question? You're using your own code here, when there is already code provided. The reason I ask is because I'm new to rufus-scheduler and this answer is going above my head.

Comment: Well, if the answer goes above your head, there isn't much I can do to help you. Do you want us yo do your work?